# Using Spring Cloud Stream Source to send method results to stream

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to create a Spring Cloud Stream Source Bean inside a Spring Boot Application that simply sends the results of a method to a stream (underlying Kafka topic is bound to the stream).

Most of the Stream samples I've seen use `@InboundChannelAdapter` annotation to send data to the stream using a poller. But I don't want to use a poller. I've tried setting the poller to an empty array but the other problem is that when using @InboundChannelAdapter you are unable to have any method parameters.

The overall concept of what I am trying to do is read from an inbound stream. Do some async processing, then post the result to an outbound stream. So using a processor doesn't seem to be an option either. I am using `@StreamListener` with a Sink channel to read the inbound stream and that works.

Here is some code i've been trying but this doesn't work at all. I was hoping it would be this simple because my Sink was but maybe it isn't. Looking for someone to point me to an example of a source that isn't a Processor (i.e. doesn't require listening on an inbound channel) and doesn't use `@InboundChannelAdapter` or to give me some design tips to accomplish what I need to do in a different way. Thanks!

```
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class JobForwarder {

   @ServiceActivator(outputChannel = Source.OUTPUT)
   @SendTo(Source.OUTPUT)
   public String forwardJob(String message) {
       log.info(String.format("Forwarding a job message [%s] to queue [%s]", message, Source.OUTPUT));
       return message;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your orginal requirement can be achieved through the below steps.

1. Create your custom Bound Interface (you can use the default `@EnableBinding(Source.class)` as well)

   ```
   public interface CustomSource {
       String OUTPUT = "customoutput";

       @Output(CustomSource.OUTPUT)
       MessageChannel output();
   }
   ```
2. Inject your bound channel

   ```
   @Component
   @EnableBinding(CustomSource.class)
   public class CustomOutputEventSource {

       @Autowired
       private CustomSource customSource;

       public void sendMessage(String message) {
           customSource.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).build());
       }
   }
   ```
3. Test it

   ```
   @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
   @SpringBootTest
   public class CustomOutputEventSourceTest {

       @Autowired
       CustomOutputEventSource output;

       @Test
       public void sendMessage() {
           output.sendMessage("Test message from JUnit test");
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

So if you don't want to use a Poller, what causes the `forwardJob()` method to be called?

You can't just call the method and expect the result to go to the output channel.

With your current configuration, you need an `inputChannel` on the service containing your inbound message (and something to send a message to that channel). It doesn't have to be bound to a transport; it can be a simple `MessageChannel` `@Bean`.

Or, you could use a `@Publisher` to publish the result of the method invocation (as well as being returned to the caller) - [docs here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/message-publishing.html).

```
@Publisher(channel = Source.OUTPUT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input. It took me a while to get back to the problem. I did try reading the documentation for `@Publisher`. It looked to be exactly what I needed but I just couldn't get the proper beans initialized to get it wired properly.

To answer your question the `forwardJob()` method is called after some async processing of the input.

Eventually I just implemented using `spring-kafka` library directly and that was much more explicit and felt easier to get going. I think we are going to stick to kafka as the only channel binding so I think we'll stick with that library.

However, we did eventually get the spring-cloud-stream library working quite simply. Here was the code for a single source without a poller.

```
@Component
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class JobForwarder {

    private Source source;

    @Autowired
    public ScheduledJobForwarder(Source source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public void forwardScheduledJob(String message) {
        log.info(String.format("Forwarding a job message [%s] to queue [%s]", message, Source.OUTPUT));
        source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).build());
    }
}
```